# Create checkbox list from array of objects with knockout

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, checkbox, knockout.js

I would like to know what is the proper way to create a list of checkboxes bound to a selected list for an array of objects using knockout. It is very straight forward using basic values like a list of words but can it be done with an array of objects.

this works:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function ViewModel(){
        self.choices = ["one","two","three","four","five"];
            self.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray(["two", "four"]);
            self.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                return self.selectedChoices().join(",");
            });
}
</script>

<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: choices">
     <li><input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: selectedChoices" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited"></div>
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to work if the items are objects like this:

```
self.choices = [{"Id":1,"Name":"one"},{"Id":2,"Name":"two"}, {"Id":3,"Name":"three"}, {"Id":4,"Name":"four"}, {"Id":5,"Name":"five"}];
self.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray([{"Id":2,"Name":"two"}, {"Id":4,"Name":"four"}]);
```

In the end I would like to be able to create checkbox lists from MultiSelectList object created in my MVC controller and passed to the view in the ViewBag.

@ebohlman answer about using CheckedValue is what I was looking for. One other note however, is that specifying the SelectedChoices directly as I did above will not work because the objects will not equal the objects in the Choices array even though the values in them are the same. Instead I've added code to push the selected choices onto the SelectedChoices array after defining it:

```
    self.choices = [{"Id":1,"Name":"one","Selected":true},{"Id":2,"Name":"two","Selected":false}];
self.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray();
$.each(self.choices, function (index, value) {
     if(value.Selected) self.selectedChoices.push(value);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `checkedValue` binding:

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedChoices" />
  <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</li>
```

And pick out the `Name` values when calculating the delimited string:

```
self.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.computed(function () {
  return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.selectedChoices(), function(v) {
    return v.Name;
  }).join(",");
});
```

Comment: Only changes is because of the way I defined my ViewModel I had to use self.selectedChoices instead of $root.selectedChoices. If I try to use $root I get an error that it is not defined.